# How to get matches error string from the last 5 line?

Tags: python

I have this script implemented from my question before in my application:

```py
def should_act():
    errors = ['+CMS ERROR: 8',
        '+CMS ERROR: 28',
        '+CMS ERROR: 29',
        '+CMS ERROR: 50',
        '+CMS ERROR: 226']

    with open("path/to/logfile.log") as f:
        for line in f:
            pass

    return any(error in line for error in errors)
```

It works by detecting errors matches in the errors dict every 3 seconds. But I just realized that it will only read a single line and when the error string is not in the last line, it won't detect as True.

For instance, I have a log file which is the target of the program:

```
# This is detected as True
[00:44:28.484] PULL START
[00:44:28.484] +CMS ERROR: 8

# Now it False
[00:44:28.484] PULL START
[00:44:28.484] +CMS ERROR: 8
[00:44:28.484] an empty space / null
```

I want it to make a `True` output on the console in range of 5 lines from the bottom. Already tried `return any(error in range(line, 5) for error in errors)` method but it gave me an exception.

Could somebody help, please?

**UPDATE**

It might be a little bit longer than I tought, please feel free to edit to make it simpler to describe.

> My program act as a third party app which is responsible to hunt error keys from the log and kill the vendor app that generates error to prevent queue overload.

I want it to ignore every errors printed above the last 5 or 20 line from the bottom to prevent the terminator script being triggered and kills the parent app (vendor app) while it is being restarted.

When the parent app got restarted, it prints out some starting line and moved the last line to about 5 or 20 lines above. If every error detected, the parent app won't start since my app is automatically terminate them. That is why I need to make it detects error only on the given range.

Here is the sample of the log file content looks like, **please note that I put some spaces to make you guys easier to find my dummy log line.** just pretend it has no space between:

```
==== WORKING EXAMPLE ====

[20:05:13.968] PULL START
[20:05:18.968] STAT - UPDATE COUNTER TO SERVER
[20:05:19.218] SEND - URL https://someniceurl.commercial
[20:05:19.468] STAT - RESPONSE = OK FOR URL = https://someniceurl.commercial
[20:05:28.609] PULL RESP NONE
[20:05:28.640] Rx - 
[20:05:28.656] STAT - 68$$"MODEM_DOWN"
[20:05:28.671] SEND - TOP UP RESPONSE, TRANS ID = XXXXXXXX, RESP CODE = 68, MESSAGE = MODEM_DOWN
[20:05:28.687] SEND-->topup?trans_id=XXXXXXXX&trans_dateXXXXXXXX&resp_code=68&ussd_msg=M1%24MODEM%5FDOWN&no_sms=1&smscid=
[20:05:28.703] RESPONSE for: topup?trans_id=XXXXXXXX&trans_dateXXXXXXXX&resp_code=68&ussd_msg=M1%24MODEM%5FDOWN&no_sms=1&smscid= --> 
[20:05:28.718] SEND - URL https://someniceurl.commercial
[20:05:28.734] STAT - RESPONSE = OK;XXXXXXXX FOR URL = https://someniceurl.commercial




[20:06:08.953] A VERY VERY LONG CONTENT HERE - +CMS ERROR: 226 <-- Error with different key




[20:05:28.953] PULL START
[20:05:45.968] PULL RESP NONE
[20:05:48.812] STAT - UPDATE COUNTER TO SERVER
[20:05:48.968] SEND - URL https://someniceurl.commercial
[20:05:49.218] PULL START
[20:05:49.468] STAT - RESPONSE = OK FOR URL = https://someniceurl.commercial
[20:05:55.296] PULL RESP NONE
[20:05:58.953] PULL START
[20:06:07.828] PULL RESP NONE
[20:06:08.953] PULL START


[20:06:08.953] A VERY VERY LONG CONTENT HERE - +CMS ERROR: 8 <-- I put this example error output manually, it works





==== NOT WORKING EXAMPLE ====

[20:05:13.968] PULL START
[20:05:18.968] STAT - UPDATE COUNTER TO SERVER
[20:05:19.218] SEND - URL https://someniceurl.commercial
[20:05:19.468] STAT - RESPONSE = OK FOR URL = https://someniceurl.commercial
[20:05:28.609] PULL RESP NONE
[20:05:28.640] Rx - 
[20:05:28.656] STAT - 68$$"MODEM_DOWN"
[20:05:28.671] SEND - TOP UP RESPONSE, TRANS ID = XXXXXXXX, RESP CODE = 68, MESSAGE = MODEM_DOWN
[20:05:28.687] SEND-->topup?trans_id=XXXXXXXX&trans_dateXXXXXXXX&resp_code=68&ussd_msg=M1%24MODEM%5FDOWN&no_sms=1&smscid=
[20:05:28.703] RESPONSE for: topup?trans_id=XXXXXXXX&trans_dateXXXXXXXX&resp_code=68&ussd_msg=M1%24MODEM%5FDOWN&no_sms=1&smscid= --> 
[20:05:28.718] SEND - URL https://someniceurl.commercial
[20:05:28.734] STAT - RESPONSE = OK;XXXXXXXX FOR URL = https://someniceurl.commercial


[20:06:08.953] A VERY VERY LONG CONTENT HERE - +CMS ERROR: 226 <-- But, it starts to detect this one, and if I remove this line it will detect the other above it. It makes my app executing the terminator script. :(


[20:05:28.953] PULL START
[20:05:45.968] PULL RESP NONE
[20:05:48.812] STAT - UPDATE COUNTER TO SERVER
[20:05:48.968] SEND - URL https://someniceurl.commercial
[20:05:49.218] PULL START



[20:06:08.953] A VERY VERY LONG CONTENT HERE - +CMS ERROR: 8 <-- I moved it here, and it does not work anymore. It is good. :)


[20:05:49.468] STAT - RESPONSE = OK FOR URL = https://someniceurl.commercial
[20:05:55.296] PULL RESP NONE
[20:05:58.953] PULL START
[20:06:07.828] PULL RESP NONE
[20:06:08.953] PULL START
```

Comment: Re. your update: "_That is why I need to make it detects error only on the given range._" So what's the given range now? A variable between 5 to 20? Your question might be getting a little too broad.

Comment: yes, a variable between 5 to 20. E.g: 15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.readlines()` to obtain the text in lines, slice it with `[-5:]` to obtain the last 5 lines, and iterate.

```
with open("path/to/logfile.log") as f:
    for line in f.readlines()[-5:]:
        for e in errors:
            if e in line:
                return True

return False
```

Equivalently:

```
with open("path/to/logfile.log") as f:
    return any(e in line for line in f.readlines()[-5:] for e in errors)
```

Regex also works:

```
import re

re.findall(r'\+CMS ERROR: (8|28|29|50|226)', s)

with open("path/to/logfile.log") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()[-5:]
    return bool(re.findall(r'\+CMS ERROR: (8|28|29|50|226)', '\n'.join(lines)))
```

`re.findall` returns a list of matches. For our particular regex, it will return a list of numbers with errors matching 8, 28, 29, 50, or 226. Passing the list to `bool` will output a `True`/`False` value.

---

You can generalise this to check for a variable-number of last lines by slicing a variable. E.g.

```
threshold = 15
with open("path/to/logfile.log") as f:
    return any(e in line for line in f.readlines()[-threshold:] for e in errors)
```

Comment: it works sir, but it detects all errors even if it was in the outside of the last 5 line when I delete the last error I manually put in the test log sample. I want to make it ignore all error if not in the last 5 line.

Comment: @Donny From my tests, the solution works. Please do update your question to clarify it. Especially the part "_even if it was in the outside of the last 5 line when I delete the last error I manually put in the test log sample_".

Answer (score 0):

With the code you are basically putting the last part of f in line.

```
with open("path/to/logfile.log") as f:
    for line in f:  # <-- this for loop does nothing except line = f[-1]
        pass

return any(error in line for error in errors)
```

Try to modify it like this:

```
with open("path/to/logfile.log", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for error in errors:
        for line in lines[-5:]:
            if error in line:
                return True
    return False
```

I would recommend to only use list comprehensions once you fully understand what they are doing. I am using Python for more than 3 years now and still avoid them.

Comment: Great, now I can mark my own answer as duplicate because @TrebledJ wrote basically the same thing and more ;-)